# UPSS does not start after full backup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

every week we perform a full backup of our SharePoint environment using the backup-spfarm command:

```
backup-spfarm -directory $directory -backupmethod full -Verbose
```

and every week, after the backup is performed, the User Profile Synchronization Service goes down. It also takes down the **Forefront Identity Manager Service** and the **Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service**.

Is there something that can be done to prevent the UPSS service from going down?

Comment: make sure the farm account in local administrator group

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. When a full backup is run (or a backup of the UPSA object), the UPSS is deprovisioned (stopped). If the Farm Administrator is a Local Administrator on the server where the UPSS is running, it should start itself when the backup process has completed.

The alternative is to switch to SQL Server-based backups.

One other thing, the reason the account must be a Local Administrator is simply that the code to start the UPSS attempts to make a call to the local machine's SAM (Security Account Manager database) which can only be performed by Local Administrators.

Comment: Thanks, will add the accounts as local admins and see what happens after the backups are run this weekend.

Comment: Keep in mind that best practice dictates that the farm account is *not* a member of the Local Admins group.

Comment: This is a requirement for the UPSS. And the Admin token sticks around until you restart services, therefor you cannot remove it from the Local Admins group.

Comment: I verified that the farm account is a member of the local admin group....it is still not restarting the service. Any thoughts on what else it could be?